# F5 client and server stay in same subnet, require log original source IP without changes on server

Tags: logging, subnet, f5

My scenario and requirements:
1. clients' IP and servers' IP stay in same IP subnet.
2. servers need log the original source IP.

How to fix this?
My understanding: SNAT +  X-Forwarded-For
1. Use SNAT to force the server send back the reply via F5 rather than send directly back to client since they stay in same subnet.
2. enable X-Forwarded-For at F5.
3. make changes on server to log the X-Forwarded-For messages.

But, can I use other solutions which no need change the configurations on server side(the server is running in production environment, ppl do not want to do any changes)?

Really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: understand that if I use SNAT and want logs for original source IP of client, I need make changes on server.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct. You will need to configure the SNAT to make sure that the client traffic goes back via the F5. You will only need to X-Forward-For header if you want to the F5 to send real client IP address information to the server.

Comment: thanks for answer, but if we want to log the original source ip of clients, we still need to do configuration on servers to extract the header right? Is there some ways maybe? I mean no need to do changes on servers and still can get the original source ip of clients at servers?

Comment: unless app server is already configured to read client ip from a header, you'll need to make that change to get the info when using snat.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so I need config the server if using SNAT.

Comment: So based on my scenario: 1)clients' IP and servers' IP stay in same IP subnet, 2)servers need log the original source IP.   Is there some other solutions except SNAT+ XFF ? It's  really hard to get permission to make change on production servers.